# Adding each character in a line of input file to list, and adding each list to another list after each line

Tags: python, list, io

Basically what I am trying to do is read in each character from each line into a list, and after each line, add that list into another list (one list per line in input file, each list containing all the individual characters of each line)

This is what I have so far but it doesnt seem to be working and I can't figure out why.

```
allseq = []
with open("input.txt", "r") as ins:
    seq = []
    for line in ins:
        for ch in line:
            if ins != "\n":
                seq.append(ch)
            else:
                allseq.append(seq)
                seq[:] = []

print(allseq)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in Python can be easily converted into literal lists of characters! Let's make a function.

```
def get_char_lists(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        return [list(line.strip()) for line in f.readlines()]
```

This opens a file for reading, reads all the lines, strips off extraneous whitespace, sticks a list of the characters into a list, and returns that last list.

Comment: Thank you! This is a much more elegant solution.

Comment: @Matt, no problem! Gotta start somewhere! :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though there is an easier way (@Pierce answer), there are two problems with your original code.  The second is important to understand.

```
allseq = []
with open("input.txt", "r") as ins:
    seq = []
    for line in ins:
        for ch in line:
            if ch != "\n":         # Use ch instead of ins here.
                seq.append(ch)
            else:
                allseq.append(seq)
                seq = []           # Don't clear the existing list, start a new one.

print(allseq)
```

Test file:

```
this is
some input
```

Output:

```
[['t', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's'], ['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'i', 'n', 'p', 'u', 't']]
```

To clarify why the 2nd fix is needed, when you append an object to a list, a reference to the object is placed in the list.  So if you later mutate that object the displayed content of the list changes, since it references the same object.  `seq[:] = []` mutates the original list to be empty.

```
>>> allseq = []
>>> seq = [1,2,3]
>>> allseq.append(seq)
>>> allseq                # allseq contains seq
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> seq[:] = []           # seq is mutated to be empty
>>> allseq                # since allseq has a reference to seq, it changes too.
[[]]
>>> seq.append(1)         # change seq again
>>> allseq                # allseq's reference to seq displays the same thing.
[[1]]
>>> allseq.append(seq)    # Add another reference to the same list
>>> allseq                
[[1], [1]]
>>> seq[:]=[]             # Clearing the list shows both references cleared.
>>> allseq
[[], []]
```

You can see that allseq contains the same references to seq with `id()`:

```
>>> id(seq)
46805256
>>> id(allseq[0])
46805256
>>> id(allseq[1])
46805256
```

`seq = []` Creates a new list with a different ID, instead of mutating the same list.

Comment: Ooh I should've pointed out where he went wrong. Thanks for filling that in! It's definitely useful for OP to be able to learn from his mistakes in addition to learning better methods of accomplishing his goals.

Answer (score 0):

If you, or anyone else, prefer a one liner, here it is (based on Pierce Darragh's excellent answer):

```
allseq = [list(line.strip()) for line in open("input.txt").readlines()]
```